# How to exclude folders from WinDirStat scan?

Tags: filesystems, exclude, windirstat

During the lifetime of a typical computer, many folders are static in their contents. For example, a program like Matlab, loaded with some toolboxes, is installed once and seldom changes ever after. It takes a large amount of disk space, but more importantly, it contains thousands of small files.

These folders substantially slow down the WinDirStat file tree scan.

The utility's interface allows to scan subtrees. But can you exclude a subtree while scanning its parent tree?

Answer (score 2):

> These folders substantially slow down the WinDirStat file tree scan.

Instead of attempting to persuade an extremely outdated utility to work efficiently, I recommend switching to a superior free tool that benefits from ongoing developer support: [TreeSize](https://customers.jam-software.de/downloadTrial.php?article_no=80).

[image]

Based on my [recent experience](https://superuser.com/questions/1472592/windows-7-stuck-discovering-files-items-remaining-when-copying-from-nas-to-pc-w/1472624) with WinDirStat, it's about 10x slower than TreeSize!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to find the FREE version download. Looks like all versions are for purchase, with a 30-day free trial period.

Comment: Nevermind. Find via Google search. It is hidden in their website.

Comment: Good point. I've fixed the URL in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

WizTree (https://diskanalyzer.com/) is also way faster so you wouldn't have that problem

SpaceSniffer (http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/) supports filters, which apart from (I guess) avoiding to scan that directory, also avoids showing it on the treemap